# How do I select the workers who make more money than their leader within their respective department in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following table:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| ID EMPNAME DEPARTMENT ROLE       SALARY   EXTRA   |
| 1  brian   10         sales      2000     500     |
| 2  jenny   10         leader     3000     100     |
| 3  sam     20         office     1500     500     |
| 4  cory    20         leader     1200     300     |
| 5  tifa    30         custservice4000     1000    |
| 6  sammy   30         leader     3000     200     |
| 7 anne     30         sales      4500     200     |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

My job is to find the people who make more than their leader (salary + extra) within each role. I will then display the `id`, `empname`, and `department` of that person. I need a way compare the salaries + extra (extra is the bonus they make each year) between roles within each department. I have tried something like the following code but it didn't work, it wasn't calculating the highest vs the leader properly.

```
SELECT a.id, a.empname, a.department
FROM MyTable a
JOIN (SELECT MAX(Salary + extra) As Highest, Dept FROM MyTable GROUP BY Dept) b
ON a.Dept = b.Dept && (a.Salary + a.extra) = b.Highest
```

How do I display the first three columns on the criteria that they make more than their leader in their specific department? The above table should output the following below:

```
+-----------------------+
| ID EMPNAME DEPARTMENT |
| 3  sam     20         |
| 5  tifa    30         |
| 7  anne    30         |
+-----------------------+
```

This is done in sql developer.

EDIT: Forgot to add that some values of `EXTRA` may be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I'm thinking a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where (t.salary + t.extra) > (select t2.salary + t2.extra
                              from mytable t2
                              where t2.department = t.department and
                                    t2.role = 'leader'
                             );
```

Comment: When I run this I just get a blank table. I forgot to mention but some of the salary or extra values might be null. is that why it isnt working? Thank you.

Comment: @BlackShard . . . (1) There are no missing values in *this* question.  (2)  Those rows would be filtered out.  If the values are missing, then it is unclear how to make the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join approach here:

```sql
SELECT mt1.id, mt1.empname, mt1.department
FROM MyTable mt1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT department, salary + COALESCE(extra, 0) AS total
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE ROLE = 'leader'
) mt2
    ON mt1.department = mt2.department
WHERE
    mt1.salary + COALESCE(mt1.extra, 0) > mt2.total;
```

Comment: I forgot to add that some values of extra may be null if they dont get a bonus, will this affect the outcome? When I ran your query I got a blank table.

Comment: @BlackShard Sure, just wrap `extra` with `COALESCE` and assign it a default value of zero in case of null.